# What is the significance of “good faith”?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, any-jurisdiction, good-faith

It’s a term that before I began getting interested in law I always had a vague/general lay understanding of and associated with law. Since I started reading about law I have never encountered a context where it is clearly significant much less important. Is this a question of jurisdiction? What is the significance and implication of one possessing (or not possessing) so called “good faith”?

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Good faith is an organizing principle in contract law, requiring, among other things, a duty to act honestly in the performance of contractual obligations. See [*Bhasin v. Hrynew*, 2014 SCC 71](https://canlii.ca/t/gf84s#par33):

> it is time to take two incremental steps in order to make the common law less unsettled and piecemeal, more coherent and more just. The first step is to acknowledge that good faith contractual performance is a general organizing principle of the common law of contract which underpins and informs the various rules in which the common law, in various situations and types of relationships, recognizes obligations of good faith contractual performance. The second is to recognize, as a further manifestation of this organizing principle of good faith, that there is a common law duty which applies to all contracts to act honestly in the performance of contractual obligations.

Good faith is also a requirement placed on executive action in administrative law. See also *Dagg v. Canada*, [1997] 2 SCR 403:

> Where the statutory discretion has been exercised in **good faith** and, where required, in accordance with the principles of natural justice, and where reliance has not been placed upon considerations irrelevant or extraneous to the statutory purpose, the courts should not interfere

Good faith is crucial to the fulfilment of the honour of the Crown, required in all dealings between the government and Indigenous peoples, particularly in fulfilment of the *duty to consult and accomodate*. See *Haida Nation v. British Columbia (Minister of Forests)*, [[2004] 3 S.C.R. 511, 2004 SCC 73](https://canlii.ca/t/1j4tq).

A fiduciary has the duty of utmost good faith and fair dealing.

Someone seeking an equitable remedy or defence should come to the court with clean hands and in good faith.

Good faith or lack thereof is considered when deciding whether evidence obtained in manner inconsistent with the *Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms* should be excluded from trial.

Answer (score 2):

[colorado](/questions/tagged/colorado)

There are several main definitions of good faith in Colorado, at least two of which are derived from the Uniform Commercial Code (UCC), and at least two regarding how it applies to non-UCC contracts. In both cases, this duty can't be waived although it can be more clearly defined, by mutual agreement.

In every contract subject to the UCC (which has been adopted with minor modification in every U.S. jurisdiction), "Every  contract  or duty within this Act imposes an obligation of good faith in its performance or enforcement." UCC § 1-203.

The UCC governs the sale and lease of tangible personal property, the use of personal property as collateral, warehouse receipts, letters of credit, electronic funds transfers, bank deposits, negotiable instruments, and the transfer of securities like stocks. Historically, it also included bulk sales, i.e. the sale of substantially all assets of a business, but this part of the UCC has been repealed in every or almost every U.S. jurisdiction. The UCC does not govern transactions involving real estate or services, other than certain financial transactions.

[Historically](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/148690135.pdf), the minimal UCC definition was "Honesty in fact in the conduct or transaction concerned." UCC § 1-201(9). A higher standard of “honesty in fact and the observance of reasonable commercial standards of fair dealing,” applied in certain other UCC contexts such as sales of goods and warehouse receipts. See, e.g. UCC §§ 2-103 (1) (b), 7-404. More recent versions of the UCC apply the more rigorous definition in all circumstances.

A third, common law definition in Colorado is that "good faith" is a duty implied in law in all contracts that requires a party with discretion regarding how a contractual provision will be performed under the contract to do so with regard to the mutual purpose of the parties to the contract in entering into the contract. *See Amoco Oil Co. v. Ervin*, [908 P.2d 493](https://law.justia.com/cases/colorado/supreme-court/1996/94sc452-0.html) (Colo. 1995).

There are subtle differences and elaborations of the common law meaning of "good faith" in the specialized fourth context of a bad faith breach of an insurance contract by an insurer, where certain conduct, like refusing to settle a case for policy limits when there is a realistic chance that the insured will face a judgment in excess of policy limits is bad faith as a matter of law.

> Since I started reading about law I have never encountered a context
> where it is clearly significant much less important. Is this a
> question of jurisdiction? What is the significance and implication of
> one possessing (or not possessing) so called “good faith”?

In Colorado, "good faith" mostly comes up in the context of sharp dealing by merchants in ordinary business transactions, and in the context of one party abusing its unilateral rights in a contract to its own advantage in a way not contemplated by the parties when the contract was entered into by the parties.

In the leading case of *Amoco Oil Co. v. Ervin*, [908 P.2d 493](https://law.justia.com/cases/colorado/supreme-court/1996/94sc452-0.html) (Colo. 1995), a landlord was given the right to determine rent as a formula based upon the value of the asset rented, and the duty of good faith and fair dealing restrained how the landlord could perform this unilateral right.